# Get info for Invalid Stripe textfield inputs

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe SDK for ios to make payments. I am using **STPPaymentCardTextField** to get card details input from the user.

I can check if details are invalid by using '**isValid**' property but my concern is how can i get which input is invalid? like how can I get if the user has entered the wrong card number or expiration date is wrong and more?

Comment: I think the component handles that internally and displays any incorrect values using the error color. So all you need to care about is the isValid property

Comment: The component only highlights wrong input but does not tell which input is wrong. My point here is that i want to show an error message to the user about his/her wrong input so I need which input is not valid. @JoakimDanielson

Comment: You have already accepted an answer so your question has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`isValid`](https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPPaymentCardTextField.html#/c:@M@Stripe@objc(cs)STPPaymentCardTextField(py)isValid) property checks that **all** of the `STPPaymentCardTextField` fields are valid. To validate each input individually, you could use [`STPCardValidator`](https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPCardValidator.html).

Note that the `STPPaymentCardTextField` will automatically highlight any incorrect values in the inputs.

Comment: Yes thanks, but in case of validation of CVC the STPCardValidator's validationStateForCVC methods ask card brand, so how can I validate CVC? how do I know the card brand that the user has entered? Is there a way?